# Int input (for a date) added to an AVL tree are incorrect

Tags: c++

My problem is in C++.

I have a class AVL tree that has been tested and works properly and a Map tree class.

I created a Map tree like this:

```
Maptree<string, Mapatree<Date, Maptree<string, int>>> personservice;
```

And then tried to add a entry to the map tree like this:

```
personservice["Mike"][Date(0, 15, 30, 30)]["Car"]++;
```

Mike and Car are properly saved in the Maptree, but the int value from Date is incorrect and in the order of 20000+.

Here are the class Maptree and Date:

```
template <class K, class V>
class Maptree
{

public:
    const V &operator[](const K &) const;
    V &operator[](const K &);

private:
    class Entries
    {
    public:
        Entries(const K &c) : key(k), value(v) {}
        K key;
        V value;
        bool operator<(const Entries &e) const { return key < e.key; }
    };
    AVLTree<Entries> entries;
};
```

```
class Date{
  public:
    Date();
    bool operator <(const Date& date) const;
    Date(int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds) {
      days = days;
      hours = hours;
      minutes = minutes;
     seconds = seconds;
    }
  private:
    int days;
    int hours; 
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
    
  friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, const Date& date);
  friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream&, Date& date);
};
```

Do you have an idea what could cause the ints value from Date to be improperly saved in the Maptree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
      days = days;
      hours = hours;
      minutes = minutes;
      seconds = seconds;
```

These four statements, in the constructor, assign the values of four constructor parameters to themselves. In other words, this does absolutely nothing at all, whatsoever. If you just look at these four lines of C++ code, outside of any context, you have to agree that they do absolutely nothing at all except to assign the values of four objects to themselves. Which is still nothing.

Your clear intent is to initialize the class members, of the same name, when constructing an instance of this class. Your C++ textbook will contain more information about properly using the initialization section of a constructor correctly, like this:

```cpp
   Date(int days, int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
       : days{days},
         hours{hours},
         minutes{minutes},
         seconds{seconds}
   {
   }
```